# MATLAB - How to set sigma in templateSVM

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset with multiple labeled vectors and I wanted to perform a multi-class SVM with RBF Kernel with the integrated function in MATLAB called 'templateSVM'.

To do so, I use the templateSVM function with the following command:

```
t = templateSVM('BoxConstraint', 1, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf')
```

The problem is that I cannot find how to set the 'sigma' parameter.

Thanks to previous computations, I know that `C=1` and `sigma=8` are the best parameters to get the best results. Not knowing how to set sigma leads me to awful results.

Would you know how to set this parameter?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the options available with `templateSVM` seem to be quite limited (I had this problem myself and couldn't find a solution). There are some crucial options (such as the RBF `sigma` parameter) that do not seem to be available with `templateSVM` but are available with `svmtrain`.

I know that this isn't a real answer to your question, but I suggest that you look into using [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) instead - it is very configurable and integrates well with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but the answer would be useful for new users.
Link below can answer the question:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336748-support-vector-machine-parameters-matlab

"setting SIGMA": Use the 'KernelScale' name-value pair.